# What are "api-ms-win-*-*-lx-x-x.dll" umbrella libraries?

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, uwp

I keep running into DLLs with long file names, as such. Just two for example: `"api-ms-win-appmodel-runtime-l1-1-1.dll"` or `"api-ms-win-appmodel-identity-l1-2-0.dll"`. Evidently Microsoft calls them "[umbrella libraries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt654040%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)".

My original understanding was that they were just new DLLs with new file names, but then I tried to search for those files. Well, I couldn't find them as physical files on disk ...

So I'm curious, are they some sort of virtual DLL file names that don't exist on disk?

```
WCHAR buff[MAX_PATH];
buff[0] = 0;
GetSystemDirectory(buff, MAX_PATH);
StringCchCat(buff, MAX_PATH, L"\\api-ms-win-appmodel-runtime-l1-1-1.dll");

HMODULE hModule = LoadLibrary(buff);
//'hModule' is NULL & error code is ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND
```

But the following works:

```
HMODULE hModule = LoadLibrary(L"api-ms-win-appmodel-runtime-l1-1-1.dll");
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

These are “Virtual DLL” names. When we call `LoadLibrary`, the Windows loader (e.g., `LdrLoadDll`) will check for well known name prefixes (ex. `api-`) and if the name begins with one of these - it will use the [ApiSetSchema mechanism](https://blog.quarkslab.com/runtime-dll-name-resolution-apisetschema-part-i.html) to translate the virtual dll name (i.e `api-ms-win..` ) to the real dll name (e.g., a file name, like `kernel32.dll`, `kernelbase.dll`, etc). this mapping is implemented in **ApiSetSchema.dll** which is located in the *system32* folder.

[image]

Regarding the internal implementation - read [Runtime DLL name resolution: ApiSetSchema - Part II](https://blog.quarkslab.com/runtime-dll-name-resolution-apisetschema-part-ii.html)  and [The API Set Schema](http://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/win32/apisetschema/index.htm).

You may also reference Microsoft's original documentation for API Set Schemas, US patent publication ["US 2014/0366045 A1"](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/d0/5f/79/2583d676e6c0de/US20140366045A1.pdf), which covers the original motivations for the technology and the overarching design that Microsoft implemented.

Comment: For compatibility with older systems, these API Set libraries are sometimes found as real DLLs that forward to an implementation DLL.

Comment: @eryksun - think this is on win8.1 only. here we really found this dlls. say exist `api-ms-win-appmodel-identity-l1-2-0.dll` in system32. and this dll export functions. but it not implement it or forward to actual implementation, but simply return 0. in win 10 not exist any `api-*` files in system32

Comment: Such DLLs exist on Windows 7 and 8 for the Universal CRT API Sets, api-ms-win-crt-*.dll. These CRT DLLs are virtual in Windows 10. In either case they're implemented by ucrtbase.dll.

Comment: @eryksun: Thank you, both. I'll review the articles that were linked here. But before that, I'm curious, what if I create a DLL with the same name in my own folder and try to load it as such: `LoadLibrary(L"api-ms-win-appmodel-runtime-l1-1-1.dll")`? It's strange that they decided to determine the "virtual-ness" by the DLL name only vs. some special GUID value in the file manifest, as they were doing with other things. Plus totally did **not** document it in the main MSDN page for `LoadLibrary`.

Comment: @c00000fd - `LdrLoadDll` at begin call internal function `ApiSetResolveToHost` which check are dll path (exactly path as is, not name only) begin  from `api-` or `EXT-` and if yes (case sensitive) - call `ApiSetpSearchForApiSet` which try redirect dll name. if this name will be redirected - redirected name will be used. but if name will be not found in apiset - this name will be continue used as is and if dll with this name really exist on disk - it will be loaded as usual

Comment: [Here's another article on the topic](https://www.nirsoft.net/articles/windows_7_kernel_architecture_changes.html).