# Differences in import table between x64dbg and my loader

Tags: dll, code-injection, dllimport, portable-executable

I'm trying to inject and manually map an executable into a running process. To do my tests, I build a "minimal" executable that only call `MessageBoxA`. When I use dumpbin to list the imported modules, I get:

> ```
> USER32.dll
> VCRUNTIME140.dll
> api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
> api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll
> api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll
> api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll
> api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll
> KERNEL32.dll
> ```

But when I look at the symbols list in x64dbg or the modules list in vs2019, I can't see any of the crt dlls. Why is the import list different from the module list once loaded? I can see why there would be more modules, but not why some of them disapear.

Also I tried to statically link these crt dlls to my executable, but couldn't do it without also statically linking vcruntime. I'd like to keep my executable small, is there a way to avoid linking the static version of vcruntime and at the same time not having those crt entries in my import list?

NB: Using windows SDK 10, toolset 142 and std:c++latest

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47530043/6401656

Comment: Never heard of this before! Thanks a lot for this link, it's exactly what I was looking for.