# What is "api-ms-win-core-..."?

Tags: windows, winapi, operating-system, internals

I have 2 questions regarding those DLLs:

1. Why do they exist? I can see that all they do is have exports that forward to functions in other modules like Kernel32 or NtDll
2. When I use LoadLibrary with one of those modules, it ends up loading something called "KernelBase.dll". What is that and why is the actual module not loaded?

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47530043/6401656

Comment: Thanks, man, that's it.