# How do I link against the ucrt library in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-c++, shared-libraries

I am trying to understand how the linking process works for C programs in VS2019. According to [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/crt-library-features?view=msvc-160), I need to pass the \MD option to link against ucrt.lib.
I wrote an empty main function and compiled+linked it to Sample.exe under two different configurations. In the default Debug configuration, the final binary produces the following output on running `dumpbin /imports Sample.exe`:

```
VCRUNTIME140D.dll
            41B098 Import Address Table
            41B2A4 Import Name Table
                 0 time date stamp
                 0 Index of first forwarder reference

               2E __vcrt_GetModuleFileNameW
               35 _except_handler4_common
               48 memset
               1D __current_exception_context
               1C __current_exception
               2F __vcrt_GetModuleHandleW
               31 __vcrt_LoadLibraryExW
               25 __std_type_info_destroy_list

ucrtbased.dll
            41B0E8 Import Address Table
            41B2F4 Import Name Table
                 0 time date stamp
                 0 Index of first forwarder reference

              2EE _seh_filter_dll
              545 strcat_s
              2E2 _register_onexit_function
              10C _execute_onexit_table
               E8 _crt_atexit
               E7 _crt_at_quick_exit
               E0 _controlfp_s
              566 terminate
              3C9 _wmakepath_s
              3E5 _wsplitpath_s
              57F wcscpy_s
               8E __stdio_common_vsprintf_s
              549 strcpy_s
               73 __p__commode
              2FA _set_new_mode
               DB _configthreadlocale
              2E3 _register_thread_local_exe_atexit_callback
               C5 _c_exit
               CA _cexit
               70 __p___argv
               6F __p___argc
              2F7 _set_fmode
              111 _exit
              476 exit
              19A _initterm_e
              199 _initterm
              162 _get_initial_narrow_environment
              196 _initialize_narrow_environment
               DC _configure_narrow_argv
               81 __setusermatherr
              2F2 _set_app_type
              2EF _seh_filter_exe
               15 _CrtDbgReportW
               14 _CrtDbgReport
              197 _initialize_onexit_table

KERNEL32.dll
            41B000 Import Address Table
            41B20C Import Name Table
                 0 time date stamp
                 0 Index of first forwarder reference

              345 HeapAlloc
              37F IsDebuggerPresent
              462 RaiseException
              3EF MultiByteToWideChar
              5FE WideCharToMultiByte
              44D QueryPerformanceCounter
              218 GetCurrentProcessId
              2E9 GetSystemTimeAsFileTime
              58C TerminateProcess
              217 GetCurrentProcess
              2AE GetProcAddress
              1AB FreeLibrary
              5CE VirtualQuery
              2B4 GetProcessHeap
              349 HeapFree
              21C GetCurrentThreadId
              261 GetLastError
              278 GetModuleHandleW
              386 IsProcessorFeaturePresent
              2D0 GetStartupInfoW
              56D SetUnhandledExceptionFilter
              5AD UnhandledExceptionFilter
              363 InitializeSListHead
```

Whereas, under the Release configuration, I am getting this:

```
    VCRUNTIME140.dll
            402034 Import Address Table
            402608 Import Name Table
                 0 time date stamp
                 0 Index of first forwarder reference

               48 memset
               1D __current_exception_context
               1C __current_exception
               35 _except_handler4_common

KERNEL32.dll
            402000 Import Address Table
            4025D4 Import Name Table
                 0 time date stamp
                 0 Index of first forwarder reference

              386 IsProcessorFeaturePresent
              37F IsDebuggerPresent
              363 InitializeSListHead
              2E9 GetSystemTimeAsFileTime
              21C GetCurrentThreadId
              5AD UnhandledExceptionFilter
              56D SetUnhandledExceptionFilter
              217 GetCurrentProcess
              58C TerminateProcess
              218 GetCurrentProcessId
              44D QueryPerformanceCounter
              278 GetModuleHandleW

api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
            402060 Import Address Table
            402634 Import Name Table
                 0 time date stamp
                 0 Index of first forwarder reference

               44 _set_app_type
               39 _initterm_e
               58 exit
               25 _exit
               35 _initialize_narrow_environment
                5 __p___argc
                6 __p___argv
               17 _cexit
               16 _c_exit
               3F _register_thread_local_exe_atexit_callback
               19 _configure_narrow_argv
               42 _seh_filter_exe
               2A _get_initial_narrow_environment
               36 _initialize_onexit_table
               3E _register_onexit_function
               1F _crt_atexit
               1D _controlfp_s
               6A terminate
               38 _initterm

api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll
            402058 Import Address Table
            40262C Import Name Table
                 0 time date stamp
                 0 Index of first forwarder reference

               2E __setusermatherr

api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll
            4020B0 Import Address Table
            402684 Import Name Table
                 0 time date stamp
                 0 Index of first forwarder reference

               54 _set_fmode
                1 __p__commode

api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll
            402050 Import Address Table
            402624 Import Name Table
                 0 time date stamp
                 0 Index of first forwarder reference

                8 _configthreadlocale

api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll
            402048 Import Address Table
            40261C Import Name Table
                 0 time date stamp
                 0 Index of first forwarder reference

               16 _set_new_mode
```

The link on top talks about how two different versions of the DLLs are used for Release and Debug configurations but here, I am linking to two different sets of DLLs. **Why is this happening?** The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/crt-library-features?view=msvc-160) say that ucrt.dll is sufficient for the Standard C library functions. **How do I just link to that?**

Also, why do I require VCRUNTIME DLL when I am not using any C++?

Comment: `The docs say that ucrt.dll is sufficient` No, the docs say that `ucrt.lib` is sufficient, and it is indeed sufficient for building. However, for [deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/universal-crt-deployment?view=msvc-160#local-deployment) the docs list "*ucrtbase.dll and a set of APISet forwarder DLLs*". You can find good pointers under [What are “api-ms-win-*-*-lx-x-x.dll” umbrella libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47529106/what-are-api-ms-win-lx-x-x-dll-umbrella-libraries) that explain the mechanics.

Comment: `why do I require VCRUNTIME` C++ exceptions, for one thing, as hinted by what's imported.